# Converter JTextField em inteiro e salvar no bd

Tags: java, conversão-de-tipo

Tenho um `JTextField` que é preenchido do banco de dados como texto, gostaria de salvar em outro BD como `int`. Alguém poderia me ajudar por gentileza?

O meu código:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO  ass_cidade(id_cidade) VALUES(?)";
try {
    pst = ConnectDB().prepareStatement(sql);

    //CidadeAtendida cidade = (CidadeAtendida) txtCidadesAtendidas.getText();

    pst.setString(1, txtCidadesAtendidas.getText());

    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!", "Cadastro efetuado com sucesso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

} catch (SQLException erro) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, erro);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O método `getText` retorna uma `String` com o valor no `JTextField`, então basicamente o que você precisa fazer é *parsear* esse valor para um inteiro.

```
int valor = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
```

Vale ressaltar que será lançada uma `NumberFormatException` se não for possível converter a `String` retornada para um número inteiro. Então se não tiver certeza que esse número sempre será um inteiro, talvez seja interessante fazer o tratamento com um `try/catch`.

Comment: Não deu certo este exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado a todos Pela ajuda, deu certo aqui.

Comment: Marque umas das respostas como correta, se alguma o ajudou Daivid. Ou, se encontrou a resposta por métiro próprio, publique uma resposta com a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando um tratamento para o valor do jTextField:

```
String valorTextField;
Integer valorIntegerTextField;
try{
    valorTextField = campoTextField.getText();
    //Capturo o valor do campoTextField e coloco em valorTextField.
    valorIntegerTextField = Integer.parseInt(valorTextField)
    //Transformo o valor de valorTextField em Integer e insiro em valorIntegerTextField.
    //Aqui pode ocorrer a exceção NumberFormatException, onde o campo de TextField conter algum valor que não seja inteiro.
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A partir daqui seria inclusão normal no banco.